# How can I send a post request to Sanity Studio in my React app?

Tags: reactjs, api, http-post, backend, sanity

I'm trying to send a post request to Sanity Studio from my React app. I want to send some user data to my backend, but I'm not sure what the backend URL is. ('http://localhost:3333/desk/user') I copy it from my sanity studio where i want to get this posted information.
Here's code and  the user data I want to send:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

export const createOrGetUser = async (response) => {
    const decoded = jwt_decode(response);

    const { name, picture, sub } = decoded;

    const user = {
        _id: sub,
        _type: 'user',
        userName: name,
        image: picture,
    }

    console.log(user);

    await axios.post('http://localhost:3333/desk/user', user);
}
```

I can get the user data from Google, but I'm having trouble sending it to my backend. Can anyone help me figure out what the backend URL is or how I can send the post request correctly?

Comment: "I'm having trouble sending it to my backend"  is not a clear description of the problem. Are you running sanity on http://localhost:3333/ ? what's the error you're getting when you try to POST the req?

Comment: I dont think that sanity is recieving my url becouse when i try to send it i've this error Status Code: 404 Not Found, i think i've incorrect url to make post request

Comment: I can get the user data from Google, but when I try to send the post request to my backend (which is running on localhost:3333), I'm getting an error message that says "404 Not Found."